# Excel formula to get current month followed by a text

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I am looking to create a formula that outputs " Metrics". For example, I would like the cell to read "August Metrics"

I am using the function below to display the current month;

=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMMM")

Comment: `=TEXT(TODAY(), "MMMM") & " Metrics"`.

Comment: Or more awkward: `=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMMM \M\etric\s")`

Comment: Funny @JvdV didn't know you could force Excel to read a letter as text rather than it's 'Excel' value by adding `\` prior to it. Fun fact.

Comment: Jup, not sure if it's universal but this escape character (backslash) is used in more languages than just Excel. For example regex. @P.b

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the Concatenate feature in Excel this is also used to combine texts from various cells

=concat(Text(TODAY(),"MMMM"), " Metrics")

Answer (score 0):

And you could have the "Metrics" in cell A1,

Then:

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMMM")&" "&A1
```

will also work.
Means that it is easy to change the text of "Metrics" if the function is used multiple times. You could also include the front space in A1 and remove that from the function.

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMMM")&A1
```